# Adding "Http://" before my address

Tags: java

i'm extracting address from a source but some extract doesnt have http:// infront of the address, how do i check if the address has http:// and if they dont how do i add the http:// infront? :O

Getting this error which i guess is due to the "lack" of http:// infront

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: www.speedtest.net
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:583)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:480)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:429)
at a.PageRead.r(PageRead.java:29)
at a.ThreadDownloaderWriter.run(ThreadDownloaderWriter.java:35)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)






 public StringBuilder readPage() {
        try {

            URL url = new URL(this.strURL);
            System.out.println(this.strURL);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String line;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            reader.close();

            return sb;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new StringBuilder("");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new StringBuilder("");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show the code you are using please.

Answer (score 19):

The literal answer to your question looks something like this:

```java
String url = ... ; // Whatever
if (!url.startsWith("http://")) {
    url = "http://" + url;
}
```

But that's still not a very good solution. For example, what about `https` URLS? How about ftp or even filesystem URLs (`file://`). And then you may want to think about things like case-sensitivity ("`http://`" != "`HTTP://`" != "`HttP://`" even though in reality they all mean the same thing and will be accepted by Java's `URL` class).

You could try being a little more careful:

```
if (!url.toLowerCase().matches("^\\w+://.*")) {
    url = "http://" + url;
}
```

This matches the beginning of the URL string against any "word character" followed by a colon (`:`) and two slashes (`//`), and then defaults it to `http://` if the protocol part of the URL is missing. This will cover significantly more cases than the original (literal) answer.

Ultimately, if someone gives you a URL without the protocol part, it's an invalid URL.

You should consider picking up a book on Java programming, as these are all basic logic/Java API issues.

Comment: The regex you're matching against is incorrect, you're only matching a single word character and not the entire url string, should be "^\\w+://.+" if you want to do it that way.

Comment: @AdamBatkin, remember that the method matches will only return true if the regex matches the entire target, you still need to append ".+" after "//" other wise the only time "^\\w+://" will return true is when the string is "<some protocol with word characters>://". This is an great reference for quickly testing regex in java http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Answer (score 6):

You can check if the adress starts with "http://" using the `startsWith()` method :

```
url.startsWith("http://");
```

which returns `true` if it is the case.

You are probably right about the missing "http://" being the problem. The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) seems to indicate that the protocol (http here) is mandatory.

Comment: I think it is likely (to tell java to use port 80), and is something you can easily check yourself. Also it would help to see the lines of your code throwing the exception.

Answer (score 2):

Well, based on your stack trace I'd say before you call `new URL(your_url)`, check if `your_url` starts with either an **http://**, **https://**, **ftp://**, or any other protocols you think you need to check for:

```
if(!your_url.startsWith("http://"))
```

If it's missing, add a default **http://** in front of `your_url`.

```
your_url = "http://" + your_url;
```

---

> Do you think this error is caused by the http:// ? –

Yes, in your stack trace:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: www.speedtest.net
```

You have a url that is `www.speedtest.net` and it needs to be `http://www.speedtest.net`. The error is caused by a missing protocol. Alternatively, it doesn't have to be `http://`, just a valid protocol like `https://`, `file://`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
String url = "www.speedtest.net"
if (!url.toLowerCase().startsWith("http://")) url = "http://" + url
```

However this does not work in all cases, because some websites may have https:// or other protocols.

Answer (score 1):

The current highest voted answer contains an incorrect regular expression. The solution below will match any protocol, upper or lower case:

```
if (!url.matches("^\\w+?://.*")) {
  url = "http://" + url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "www.google.com";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("http://");

Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

if (m.lookingAt()){


  System.out.println("Its already there");

}
else{

       String ss = "http://"+s;

       System.out.println(ss);

 }
```

Comment: This is an overkill for what can be achieved with `String#startsWith`, and it doesn't account for `s` being in upper-case. Why so many brackets in Pattern#compile?